# How do I set custom drawer items to "focused" dynamically?

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-paper

My end goal here is to give a few drawer items custom background colors depending on a few states set elsewhere. I understand that in order to give unique background colors to drawer items, I need to set up custom drawer content. However, I am having an issue in which I cannot get the custom drawer icons to know if they are in focus or not.

I originally thought that I could just do a `const [bHomeFocused, setbHomeFocused] = useState(false)` (etc) and setting state on `onPress` and then setting the `focused` property on that, but when a bunch more drawer items come in, I think that sounds like an unwieldy solution.

I'm sure there is a simple answer that I'm missing, as non-custom DrawerItems have this functionality inherently...

```
import { Drawer } from 'react-native-paper'
import { createDrawerNavigator, DrawerNavigationProp, DrawerItem, DrawerContentScrollView, DrawerItemList, DrawerContentComponentProps, DrawerContentOptions } from '@react-navigation/drawer';

function CustomDrawerContent(props: DrawerContentComponentProps<DrawerContentOptions>) {

    return (
        <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
            <Drawer.Section>
                <DrawerItem
                    label="Dashboard"
                    labelStyle={{ color: colorTheme.normalText }}
                    icon={() => <Icon name="book" type="feather" size={26} color={colorTheme.normalText} />}
                    activeBackgroundColor={colorTheme.panel}
                    inactiveBackgroundColor={colorTheme.cyan}
                    onPress={() => {
                        props.navigation.navigate('Dashboard')
                    }}
                />
            </Drawer.Section>
            <DrawerItem
                label="Home"
                labelStyle={{ color: colorTheme.normalText }}
                icon={() => <Icon name="home" type="feather" size={26} color={colorTheme.normalText} />}
                activeBackgroundColor={colorTheme.panel}
                inactiveBackgroundColor={colorTheme.red}
                onPress={() => {
                    props.navigation.navigate('HomeStack')
                }}
            />
        </DrawerContentScrollView>
    );
}

export type DrawerParamList = {
    Dashboard: undefined;
    HomeStack: undefined;
};

export type DrawerProps<T extends keyof DrawerParamList> = {
    navigation: DrawerNavigationProp<DrawerParamList, T>;
    route: RouteProp<DrawerParamList, T>;
};

const AppDrawer = createDrawerNavigator<DrawerParamList>();

export default function MainDrawer({ route, navigation }: TopLevelStackProps<"MainDrawer">) {

    return (
        <AppDrawer.Navigator
            drawerStyle={globalStyles.drawer}
            drawerContent={
                (props) => <CustomDrawerContent {...props} />
            }
            drawerContentOptions={{
                labelStyle: { color: colorTheme.normalText },
                activeBackgroundColor: colorTheme.panel,
                inactiveBackgroundColor: colorTheme.background,
            }}
        >
            <AppDrawer.Screen
                name="Dashboard"
                component={Dashboard}
                options={{
                    unmountOnBlur: true,
                }}
            />
            <AppDrawer.Screen
                name="HomeStack"
                component={HomeStack}
                options={{
                    unmountOnBlur: true,
                }}
            />
        </AppDrawer.Navigator>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no `focused` prop which you can use to get the current focused route.

Instead, use the props that are received by the component by the DrawerNavigator. Check out [this doc](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator/#drawercontent).

If you see the list of props passed to the `drawerContent` component, you can see the `state` prop. From the doc,

> `state` - The navigation state of the navigator, `state.routes` contains list of all routes

So you can get the array of routes, and current index, which indicates which screen is currently focused. You can get the `route name` and compare it with the item name in your list.

```
const {state} = props
const {routes, index} = state; //Not sure about the name of index property. Do check it out by logging the 'state' variable.
const focusedRoute = routes[index];
```

Comment: That's great. I was able to extend this reasoning a bit to set the drawer item with

`focused={props.state.index === props.state.routes.findIndex(e => e.name === "Dashboard")}`

Works great!

Comment: I did! Thank you. Unfortunately because I'm new here, my cast votes do not appear publicly.

Comment: Not sure if something changed at some point, but there is a `focused` prop. This works: `      <Drawer.Screen name="My Profile" component={ProfileScreen} options={{
        drawerIcon: ({ focused }) => <AntDesign name="profile" size={icons.size} color={focused ? drawerActiveTintColor : drawerInactiveTintColor} />
      }} />`